# cygwin/sshd and Virtualbox

Tags: cygwin, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using vagrant/VirtualBox on my Window (8.1) Laptop to start up a linux-test-vm from a Cygwin terminal... `vagrant up`, `vagrant ssh`, everything is working fine.

Now I want to work on that environment remotely from my main Linux-Workstation, so I've set up `sshd` in Cygwin and I can successfully ssh into my Windows-Box (same user as logged in locally in windows).

But when I `cd`'ed (via my remote ssh connection to windows-laptop) in my working directory and ran `vagrant ssh`, it tells me:

`VM must be created before running this command. Run 'vagrant up' first`

But I see the VM is running in VirtualBox GUI on Windows.

From this point on even locally on the Windows machine I can no longer interact with the running vagrant vm and the `.vagrant` (sub)directory has not files inside.

---

Same happens vice versa:

- I stopped/deleted the VM in VirtualBox GUI
- ran `vagrant up` via my ssh connection ... worked
- ran `vagrant ssh` via my ssh connection ... works
- but I do not see the VM in VirtualBox GUI on Windows
- trying `vagrant ssh` locally on Windows ... same error again and `.vagrant` directory gets cleared

---

So I assume the Cygwin/sshd connection creates some sort of different Sessions that do not share the same "instance" of VirtualBox.

Is there any chance to share VirtualBox/vagrant environment between the local Windows and remote ssh session ???

**WORKAROUND:**

- export ssh-config on the windows host: `vagrant ssh-config > ssh_config`
- from the cygwin/ssh jump into the VM: `ssh -F ssh_config default`
- **never** run any `vagrant` command from the cygwin/ssh connection

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant has a built-in solution since the 1.7.x versions called `vagrant share` which also allows you to remote into a box directly (bypassing the Windows host abstraction). It is generally used for the HTTP feature (eg. to show clients or others on a project the current state of work) but there is the ability to connect to any service running on any port. From [the docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/):

> Just call `vagrant share`. This will automatically share as many ports
>   as possible for remote connections. If the Vagrant environment has a
>   static IP or DNS address, then every port will be available.
>   Otherwise, Vagrant will only expose forwarded ports on the machine.
>
> Note the share name at the end of calling `vagrant share`, and give this
>   to the person who wants to connect to your machine. They simply have
>   to call `vagrant connect NAME`. This will give them a static IP they can
>   use to access your Vagrant environment.

Note to use `vagrant share` you need a (free) account with hashicorp.